# How to create a hyperlink in Flutter widget?

Tags: flutter

I would like to create a hyperlink to display in my Flutter app.

The hyper link should be embedded in a `Text` or similar text views like:

`The last book bought is <a href='#'>this</a>`

Any hint to do this?

Comment: [Hyperlink in Flutter](https://androidride.com/flutter-hyperlink-text/)

Answer (score 337):

Just wrap an InkWell around a Text widget and supply an UrlLauncher (from the service library) to the onTap attribute. Install [UrlLauncher](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher#-installing-tab-) as a Flutter package before using it below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('UrlLauncher'),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: new InkWell(
              child: new Text('Open Browser'),
              onTap: () => launch('https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/UrlLauncher-class.html')
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can supply a style to the Text widget to make it look like a link.

### Update

After looking into the issue a little I found a different solution to implement the 'in line' hyperlinks you asked for. You can use the [RichText Widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) with enclosed [TextSpans](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/TextSpan-class.html).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('UrlLauchner'),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: new RichText(
            text: new TextSpan(
              children: [
                new TextSpan(
                  text: 'This is no Link, ',
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                new TextSpan(
                  text: 'but this is',
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                  recognizer: new TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTap = () { launch('https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/UrlLauncher-class.html');
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This way you can actually highlight one word and make a hyperlink out of it ;)

Comment: UrlLauncher is no longer part of flutter, it was moved to [a plugin and API changed](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher).

Comment: Also we need to add imports:
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

Comment: You are not handling the lifecycle of your `TapGestureRecognizer` correctly. You have to call `dispose()` method when `RichText` is no longer used. See here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextSpan/recognizer.html

Comment: @AlexSemeniuk In your example they are using a StatefulWidget, in the answer above it is a StatelessWidget. Are you sure we need to dispose the the case of a StatelessWidget?

Comment: @CoreyCole `StatelessWidget` will not magically dispose your `TapGestureRecognizer` for you. In fact, using `StatelessWidget` in this scenario is incorrect, since you can not dispose your rsources this way. And yes, you _absolutely_ need to call `dispose()` method of `TapGestureRecognizer`, since it runs the internal timer which needs to be stopped.

Comment: Thanks Alex, yes I definitely noticed memory leak problems in logcat when I tried using a StatelesWidget for this

Comment: Simpler than RichText: `new InkWell(child: new Text('linktext', style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, decoration: TextDecoration.underline),), onTap: () => {})),`

Comment: Gosh, flutter changed another api and broke working code? Who'da thought...? (sigh)

Comment: the launch(' ') is deprecated use launchUrl(Uri.parse(' '))  the old: ..onTap = () { launch('https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/UrlLauncher-class.html');
                  },  New  ..onTap = () { launchUrl(Uri.parse('https://androidride.com'));
                            },

Comment: The URL in the example gives a HTTP 404. Also, the new method seems to be `launchUrlString()` instead of `launch()`.

Comment: `new` is not needed in Dart these days...

Answer (score 113):

Flutter doesn't have built-in hyperlink support but you can fake it yourself. There's an example in the [Gallery's drawer.dart](https://github.com/flutter/gallery/blob/master/lib/pages/about.dart). They use a `RichText` widget containing a coloured `TextSpan`, which has a `recognizer` attribute to handle taps:

```
        RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                style: bodyTextStyle,
                text: seeSourceFirst,
              ),
              TextSpan(
                style: bodyTextStyle.copyWith(
                  color: colorScheme.primary,
                ),
                text: repoText,
                recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                  ..onTap = () async {
                    final url = 'https://github.com/flutter/gallery/';
                    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
                      await launch(
                        url,
                        forceSafariVC: false,
                      );
                    }
                  },
              ),
              TextSpan(
                style: bodyTextStyle,
                text: seeSourceSecond,
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But this is not really the thing I am looking for: I am looking beyond in-app navigation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "looking beyond in-app navigation." Do you want the link to open a browser?

Comment: Yes, a link or alike that can be clicked to open in a browse.

Comment: That is what the sample I linked to does. I added some pictures to the answer to show it.

Comment: The repo link is broken

Comment: Actual code here would be appreciated since the link no longer works

Comment: How can this work with multiple languages though? Link might be in another location for example.

Comment: New url_launcher usage: final url =
                      Uri.parse('https://github.com/flutter/gallery/');
                  if (!await launchUrl(url)) {
                    throw Exception('Could not launch $url');
                  }

Answer (score 89):

### Update (Android >= 11):

- ##### iOS configuration:

  Open `info.plist` file and add:

  ```
  <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>https</string>
  </array>
  ```
- ##### Android configuration:

  Open `AndroidManifest.xml` file located in `app/src/main` and add the following at the root:

  ```xml
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <!-- Add this query -->
      <queries>
          <intent>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
              <data android:scheme="https" />
          </intent>
      </queries>

      <application ... />

  </manifest>
  ```

##### Flutter code:

Simply wrap your `Text` in a `GestureDetector` or `InkWell` and handle click in `onTap()` using [`url_launcher`](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package.

```dart
InkWell(
  onTap: () => launchUrl(Uri.parse('https://www.google.com')),
  child: Text(
    'Click here',
    style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline, color: Colors.blue),
  ),
)
```

##### Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You are right, your solution has less lines than others', but Inkwell is the widget for this especific job, so al least semantically I think It's the best solution

Comment: @dmarquina Yes, you can use `InkWell` instead of `GestureDetector`.

Comment: In web browsers GestureDetector does not change cursor and does not have onHover behavior. InkWell is a better solution.

Comment: Thanks, in my case .. this is the only code that works perfectly!

Answer (score 25):

You can use package flutter_linkify 
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_linkify 
 
Just want to provide another option. 
Package will divide your text and highlight http/https automatically 
Combine plugin url_launcher you can launch url 
You can check example below:

[image]

full code below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_linkify/flutter_linkify.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() => runApp(new LinkifyExample());

class LinkifyExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'flutter_linkify example',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('flutter_linkify example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Linkify(
            onOpen: _onOpen,
            text: "Made by https://cretezy.com \n\nMail: example@gmail.com \n\n  this is test http://pub.dev/ ",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _onOpen(LinkableElement link) async {
    if (await canLaunch(link.url)) {
      await launch(link.url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $link';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How can you have 2 links on same widget? Like for example "by clicking this you accept terms of use and privacy policy" where we need to have them together

Comment: Awesome package. Saves a lot of boiler plate code

Comment: @Dani you can add as many links as you want because the flutter linkify package treats every link different. I have tested the above snippet for more than 1 link and it works perfectly

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was searching for

Comment: The API has changed so the example above doesn't work anymore - see https://github.com/Cretezy/flutter_linkify/issues/112 for an example using the new `canLaunchUrl` and `launchUrl` instead.

Answer (score 12):

Adding one more simple and neat trick because the above ones are over-complicated for some use cases. I did it using RichText - WidgetSpan, TextButton and [URL launcher package](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher). Just modify the below example block according to your needs.

Result: [image: Result]

Code:

```dart
class UserAgreementText extends StatelessWidget {
  const UserAgreementText({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: RichText(
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            text: TextSpan(
              text: 'By logging in, you accept our ',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
              children: const <InlineSpan>[
                WidgetSpan(
                  alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.baseline,
                  baseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                  child: LinkButton(
                      urlLabel: "Terms and Conditions",
                      url: "https://example.com/terms-and-conditions"),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: ' and ',
                ),
                WidgetSpan(
                  alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.baseline,
                  baseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                  child: LinkButton(
                      urlLabel: "Privacy Policy",
                      url: "https://example.com/privacy-policy"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

link_button.dart

```dart
class LinkButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const LinkButton({Key? key, required this.urlLabel, required this.url})
      : super(key: key);

  final String urlLabel;
  final String url;

  Future<void> _launchUrl(String url) async {
    final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

    if (!await launchUrl(uri)) {
      throw 'Could not launch $uri';
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
        ),
        tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
        minimumSize: const Size(0, 0),
        textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        _launchUrl(url);
      },
      child: Text(urlLabel),
    );
  }
}
```

**Note**: If you get an error related to calling `launchUrl`, make sure you install the [URL launcher package](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) and then rebuild your application.

Comment: If you receive the error `flutter Intrinsics are not available for PlaceholderAlignment.baseline` then remove `alignment` and `baseline` from `WidgetSpan`.

Answer (score 8):

[image: flutter link widget]

In Flutter 2.0, the Link widget was introduced. Use this widget to launch webpages and also navigate to new screens in your app. you need to use the url_launcher package before using it.

```
url_launcher: ^6.0.8
```

[For More Information](https://androidride.com/flutter-hyperlink-text/)

```
Link(
              uri: Uri.parse('https://androidride.com'),
              //target: LinkTarget.self,
              builder: (context, followLink) {
                return RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(children: [
                    TextSpan(
                      text: 'Click here: ',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextSpan(
                      text: 'AndroidRide',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 21,
                      ),
                      recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                        ..onTap = followLink,
                    ),
                  ]),
                );
              }),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Link(
          uri: Uri.parse('/second'),
          builder: (context, followLink) {
            return InkWell(
              onTap: followLink,
              child: Text(
                'Go to Second Screen',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
```

Comment: To clarify, the `Link` widget is part of the `url_launcher` package, not Flutter proper.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to make it look even more like a link, you can add underline:

```
new Text("Hello Flutter!", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, decoration: TextDecoration.underline),)
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: It is not clickable!

Comment: Then wrap it around with Button widget. :)

Comment: This is not the answer to the question, but a comment to somebody's answer. Also button isn't inline text hyperlink.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Link Text https://pub.dev/packages/link_text
and use it like

```dart
 final String _text = 'Lorem ipsum https://flutter.dev\nhttps://pub.dev'; 
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
     body: Center(
      child: LinkText(
        text: _text,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Under Linux `flutter pub get` for it fails with `Unable to find a plugin.vcxproj for plugin "url_launcher_windows"`

Comment: This is limited only to making links clickable. not a word, pointing to a link

Comment: If the url itself is allowed to be visible, this is hands down the easiest solution to implement instead of an existing Text widget. If you need the url not visible but as a link behind other text, this does not work as is. Bonus: it also makes AlertDialog links clickable.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html) plugin if you want to have more advanced text capabilities:

```
Html(
  data: 'The last <i><u><b>book</b></u></i> bought is <a href="#">this</a>',
  onLinkTap: (url, context, attrs, element) {
    // Handle link tapped...
  },
)
```

This is just the tip of the iceberg of capabilities with this plugin.

*Just a thought*: You could even host parts of your flutter app online as html and render them in flutter as widgets with this plugin.

Answer (score 3):

As of 14 Sep 2023, Flutter has an inbuilt `LinkedText` widget to handle link taps: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/125927

(Example copied from the PR. Checkout the PR description for more examples.)

[image: multiple link texts]

```dart
LinkedText.textLinkers(
  text: text,
  textLinkers: <TextLinker>[
    TextLinker(
      rangesFinder: TextLinker.urlRangesFinder,
      linkBuilder: InlineLinkedText.getDefaultLinkBuilder(_onTapUrl),
    ),
    TextLinker(
      rangesFinder: TextLinker.rangesFinderFromRegExp(RegExp(r'@[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,15}')),
      linkBuilder: (String linkText) {
        return InlineLink(
          text: linkText,
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xff00aaaa),
          ),
          onTap: _onTapTwitterHandle,
        );
      },
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Looks like they have reverted this - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/134955

Answer (score 2):

The answers to this question that suggest using `RichText` with a `TextSpan` + `GestureRecognizer` are all functionally correct, but from the UX perspective, they do not provide feedback to the user responding to the touch. To maintain consistency with other Material widgets, you could use a similar approach, but use a `WidgetSpan` + `InkWell` instead.

This example uses the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package and an unstyled InkWell, but you can customize as you see fit:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class TextWithLink extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextWithLink({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const textStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.black); // default style for all text
    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        style: textStyle,
        children: [
          const TextSpan(
            text: 'The last book bought is ',
          ),
          WidgetSpan(
              alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle,
              child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () => _launchUrl('https://url-to-launch.com'),
                  child: Text('this',
                      style: textStyle.merge(const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))))), // override default text styles with link-specific styles
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _launchUrl(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a turn-key package
https://pub.dev/packages/link_text

```
child: LinkText(
  'Hello check http://google.com',
  textStyle: ...,
),
```

Safer to use a library for this kind of complexity

Pros:

- takes in the entire string as a single param
- parses the links and renders them into the UI as clickable , inline with the non-clickable text
- no complex RichText structure required

Answer (score 2):

I see a lot of verbose answers here that don't work so well.

If you want to do this from user generated content you can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown

This works on all platforms and is highly dynamic and customisable.

Comment: Would you provide an example on how to use it for links?

Answer (score 1):

**An alternative (or not) way to put clickable links in your app** *(for me it just worked that way):*

1 - Add the url_launcher package in your pubspec.yaml file

*(the package version 5.0 didn't work well for me, so I'm using the 4.2.0+3).*

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  url_launcher: ^4.2.0+3
```

2 - Import it and use as below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Navigation Basics',
    home: MyUrl(),
  ));
}

class MyUrl extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Url Launcher'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: _launchURL,
          child: Text('Launch Google!',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _launchURL() async {
    const url = 'https://google.com.br';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If need a hyperlink between some text, you can use a `FlatButton` with same background and text colors as the rest of your texts, so format it whith TextDecoration.underline as the bartektartanus showed above...

Answer (score 1):

Let's separate this question to 2 things:

1. How to embed a link inside a line of text
2. How to launch a url in an external browser/window

For #2: As posted here - use url_launcher

For #1:
I think using RichText is an overkill for this, I simply used Text's and TextButton, in a Wrap container like so:

```
Wrap(
  alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
  runAlignment: WrapAlignment.center,
  crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
  children: [
    const Text('The last book bought is'),
    TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        launchUrl(Uri.parse('https://someurl'), mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
      },
      child: const Text('this')),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I liked to create my own solution to this to see what happens so here is the result,

```
TextSpan linkify(BuildContext context, String rawText) {
  final spans =
      rawText.split(RegExp('(?=https?://|mailto:|tel:)')).indexed.expand((e) {
    final (i, chunk) = e;
    final index = i == 0 ? 0 : chunk.indexOf(RegExp('\\s|\\)|\$'));
    final link = chunk.substring(0, index);
    return [
      if (i != 0)
        TextSpan(
          text: link.replaceFirst(RegExp('^(mailto|tel):'), ''),
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall?.copyWith(
                decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
              ),
          recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
            ..onTap = () => launchUrl(Uri.parse(link)),
        ),
      TextSpan(
        text: chunk.substring(index),
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
      ),
    ];
  });
  return TextSpan(children: [...spans]);
}
```

Example:

```
const rawText = '''Here is a sample test http://example.com (https://example.com)

Contact: mailto:example@example.com and tel:+1-555-5555-555

https://example.com''';

RichText(text: linkify(context, rawText))
```

[image: output from raw code]

Note the `tel:` and `mailto:` are removed, one possibly could find mail and telephone themselves but I preferred to mark them explicitly then remove them.