# How to linkify text in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there an easy way in Flutter to 'linkify' a text that might contain a mix of plain text, emails and web URLs? E.g. if my text is `My phone number is 099 123 45 67 and my email is test@test.com` the phone number and the email would be rendered as clickable links.

In Android it would be a one liner:

```
textView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL);
```

I've seen that a similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43583411/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-in-flutter-widget). That solution would work fine for static texts, but for dynamic texts it would be a lot more complicated to parse the text, detect all URLs, phone numbers, emails etc. and use `TextSpan`s to render them accordingly.

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe you can copy the link parser from the android source code?

Comment: I also couldn't find any. I will probably use `RegExp` to get matches for phone numbers, emails and URLs, and use `TextSpan` to render them properly. Just wanted to know if there was some library I was missing before re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: [Flutter Hyperlink example](https://androidride.com/flutter-hyperlink-text/)

Answer (score 20):

I created a new package for this: [flutter_linkify](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_linkify). It currently only supports URLS, but you can always submit an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/Cretezy/flutter_linkify) with feature requests.

Baisc usage:

```
import 'package:flutter_linkify/flutter_linkify.dart';

Linkify(
  onOpen: (url) => print("Clicked $url!"),
  text: "Made by https://cretezy.com",
);
```

Comment: add features to open system apps,emails,third party apps ,phone number to call

Comment: how can we do it in Dart only, not in Flutter? Expected output: `Made by <a href="https://cretezy.com">https://cretezy.com</a>`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Kamlesh You can use the Dart-only library https://pub.dev/packages/linkify, however it's a bit lower level. It should provide all the utilities to parse the text, however you will need to write your own HTML generator for it.

Comment: Can u show how youve set $url then i restore your point

Answer (score 9):

Thank you @Charles Crete for creating that library.

I just want to add one more solution here by combining RichText, TextSpan and TapGestureRecognizer (all are in Flutter framework)

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(HyperLinkDemo());
}

class HyperLinkDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(children: [
              TextSpan(
                  text: 'This is a very long text, but you can not click on it. ',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black)),
              TextSpan(
                  text: 'And this is a clickable text',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                  recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTap = () {
                      print('You clicked on me!');
                    })
            ])),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the result

[image]

Comment: I believe the OP is asking about code to automatically detect phone numbers, addresses, or links, not just hardcoding some text as 'clickable.'

Comment: You may be correct. I just wanted to provide an additional method, so someone could use it. Anyway, why vote down? :)

Comment: My vote down is for not handling life cycle of `TapGestureRecognizer` correctly (you are not alone in this). You have to explicitly call `dispose()` method as is stated in the docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextSpan/recognizer.html

Comment: how can we do it in Dart only, not in Flutter? Expected output: `Made by <a href="https://cretezy.com">https://cretezy.com</a>`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9):

Here is how I implemented it - use the `buildTextWithLinks` function to get a `Text` component with links.

It uses url_launcher and currnetly supports URL, mail and phone links, but can easily be expanded by adding more `RegExp`s and handlers.

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

Text buildTextWithLinks(String textToLink) => Text.rich(TextSpan(children: linkify(textToLink)));

Future<void> openUrl(String url) async {
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}

const String urlPattern = r'https?:/\/\\S+';
const String emailPattern = r'\S+@\S+';
const String phonePattern = r'[\d-]{9,}';
final RegExp linkRegExp = RegExp('($urlPattern)|($emailPattern)|($phonePattern)', caseSensitive: false);

WidgetSpan buildLinkComponent(String text, String linkToOpen) => WidgetSpan(
    child: InkWell(
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
          decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
        ),
      ),
      onTap: () => openUrl(linkToOpen),
    )
);

List<InlineSpan> linkify(String text) {
  final List<InlineSpan> list = <InlineSpan>[];
  final RegExpMatch match = linkRegExp.firstMatch(text);
  if (match == null) {
    list.add(TextSpan(text: text));
    return list;
  }

  if (match.start > 0) {
    list.add(TextSpan(text: text.substring(0, match.start)));
  }

  final String linkText = match.group(0);
  if (linkText.contains(RegExp(urlPattern, caseSensitive: false))) {
    list.add(buildLinkComponent(linkText, linkText));
  }
  else if (linkText.contains(RegExp(emailPattern, caseSensitive: false))) {
    list.add(buildLinkComponent(linkText, 'mailto:$linkText'));
  }
  else if (linkText.contains(RegExp(phonePattern, caseSensitive: false))) {
    list.add(buildLinkComponent(linkText, 'tel:$linkText'));
  } else {
    throw 'Unexpected match: $linkText';
  }

  list.addAll(linkify(text.substring(match.start + linkText.length)));

  return list;
}
```

Comment: Great! thanks for this answer. You save our one more dependency. Just one thing here is that `urlPattern` wasn't working by copying this code, though it worked when I changed it to `const String urlPattern = 'https?:/\/\\S+';`

Comment: @Smit Not sure what you changed. Removed the raw prefix (`r`)?

Comment: Yes. that's correct. Can you please explain what is the significance of `r` ?

Comment: The `r` prefix indicates a [raw string](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#strings). When defining a [RegExp](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-core/RegExp-class.html) it is usually a good idea to use raw strings, so special RegExp charachters are treated properly, and not as a string escape sequnces.

Answer (score 5):

This function can auto detect what is hyper link in textview. You can modify
Regx pattern depend on your requirements.

```
List<TextSpan> extractText(String rawString) {
List<TextSpan> textSpan = [];

final urlRegExp = new RegExp(
    r"((https?:www\.)|(https?:\/\/)|(www\.))[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,6}(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]*)?");

getLink(String linkString) {
  textSpan.add(
    TextSpan(
      text: linkString,
      style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
      recognizer: new TapGestureRecognizer()
        ..onTap = () {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: linkString);
        },
    ),
  );
  return linkString;
}

getNormalText(String normalText) {
  textSpan.add(
    TextSpan(
      text: normalText,
      style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    ),
  );
  return normalText;
}

rawString.splitMapJoin(
  urlRegExp,
  onMatch: (m) => getLink("${m.group(0)}"),
  onNonMatch: (n) => getNormalText("${n.substring(0)}"),
);

return textSpan;}
```

**Usages**

```
child: SelectableText.rich(
                TextSpan(
                    children: extractText(dummyText),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: _fontSize)),
              )
```

**Here is result**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check this library [flutter_autolink_text](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_autolink_text). Is very similar to [flutter_linkify](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_linkify) but it adds support to phone number as well.

This is how to use it.

```
import 'package:flutter_autolink_text/flutter_autolink_text.dart';

AutolinkText(
    text: ...,
    textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    linkStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
    onWebLinkTap: (link) => print('Clicked: ${link}'),
    onEmailTap: (link) => print('Clicked: ${link}'),
    onPhoneTap: (link) => print('Clicked: ${link}')
);
```

Comment: Doesn't work with the link like https://welinq.io It works only when it is like www.welinq.io

Comment: Not compatible with Dart 3, bummer :(

Answer (score 0):

This plugin named linker (https://github.com/best-flutter/linker/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart)

is going to help you.

You can open phone number to call

you can open other system apps or system settings

You can open any 3rd party apps using this package..

you can open email

This package is available in pub.dev ...Search **Linker** to get it