# Make specific parts of a text clickable in flutter

Tags: text, flutter, dart, clickable

I want to make a part of a text tapable so I can call a function on it. Also I want to have control over the style of the tapable text. In the best case I can also increase the size of the tapable area to for example 42px.

[image]

I already looked into flutter_linkify and linkify, but that's not what I want. I'm curious if there's already a package or even built into the flutter library.

Comment: Using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_linkify is easier, look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52395715/4683601

Comment: Linkify is something different as it does following:
"Turns text URLs and emails into clickable inline links in text for Flutter."

Answer (score 226, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
```

Use [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) with [TextSpan](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextSpan-class.html) and [GestureRecognizer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/GestureRecognizer-class.html). With `GestureRecognizer` you can detect *tap*, *double tap*, *long press* and etc.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle defaultStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 20.0);
    TextStyle linkStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.blue);
    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        style: defaultStyle,
        children: <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(text: 'By clicking Sign Up, you agree to our '),
          TextSpan(
              text: 'Terms of Service',
              style: linkStyle,
              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                ..onTap = () {
                  print('Terms of Service"');
                }),
          TextSpan(text: ' and that you have read our '),
          TextSpan(
              text: 'Privacy Policy',
              style: linkStyle,
              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                ..onTap = () {
                  print('Privacy Policy"');
                }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Works great! Note that you'll need to `import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';` for this to work.

Comment: Can you please explain the `..` notation, I haven't seen it before.

Comment: `..` notation a allows you to call a particular method, then return the original object on which the method is call, generally used when we want to call multiple methods on the same object in a cascade fashion

Comment: I have a string fetching from database eg `nice concept of help/support  - https://support.google.com/firebase?authuser=0#topic=6399725` now tell me how an I convert this URL from this string as Link in Flutter? Thanks a lot.

Comment: richtext is not respecting text styles though, I use same `TextStyle` for TextSpan as for Text but they look different (textspan uses smaller font still)

Answer (score 35):

You can use [`RichText`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) to merge a list of [`TextSpan`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextSpan-class.html) into a single Text.

```dart
    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: 'Hello ',
        style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
        children: <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(
              text: 'world!',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          TextSpan(
              text: ' click here!',
              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                ..onTap = () => print('click')),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: What do the two dots before onTap mean?

Comment: @user3808307 this is the Cascade notation - https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation-. It helps you to make a chain of operations in the same object, as it returns an instance of the underlying object. So in this case we're implementing the `onTap()` method of the `TapGestureRecognizer` but still returning its instance to `recognizer` property from `TextSpan`

Comment: Like a spread operator?

Comment: If you're talking about the JS spread operator, it's applied to iterables and it allows us the privilege to obtain a list of parameters from an array. So no, those are different things.

Comment: I have a string fetching from database eg `nice concept of help/support  - https://support.google.com/firebase?authuser=0#topic=6399725` now tell me how an I convert this URL from this string as Link in Flutter? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey, @Kamlesh I'm afraid I didn't understand your question, can you give me more context?