# change single char style inside string when it will be clicked flutter

Tags: string, flutter, onclick, char, position

for example i have word welcome i want to change color of c when ever user clicks the letter c i get the position but i can not chnage this position to an index of the string.
i used RichText for using different style in one string and this is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:positioned_tap_detector/positioned_tap_detector.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  RichText rich;
  String word;
  String letter;
  String pressedLetter;
  Color color = Colors.black;
  TapPosition _position = TapPosition(Offset.zero, Offset.zero);
  int x=0;
  int y=0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    word = 'ویژدان';
    letter = 'د';
    var blackRt = new GestureDetector(
        child: Text(
          word,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            color = Colors.red;
          });
        });
    var redRt = useDifferentDesignInAString(word, Colors.red);
    Widget currentRT = new Container();
    if (color == Colors.black)
      currentRT = blackRt;
    else if (color == Colors.red) currentRT = redRt;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: PositionedTapDetector(
        onTap: _onTap,
          child: currentRT,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  void _onTap(TapPosition position)  {
    setState((){
      _position = position;

  x=position.global.dx.toInt();
  y=position.global.dy.toInt();
  String pressed=word[offset];

    });
  }


  RichText useDifferentDesignInAString(String word, Color color) {
    String firstPart = "";
    String remain = "";
    RichText richText;
    if (word.startsWith(letter)) {
      richText = RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          text: letter,
          style: TextStyle(color: color, fontSize: 25),
          children: <TextSpan>[
            TextSpan(
                text: word.substring(1, word.length),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 25)),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else if (word.endsWith(letter)) {
      richText = RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          text: word.substring(0, word.length - 2),
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 25),
          children: <TextSpan>[
            TextSpan(text: letter, style: TextStyle(color: color, fontSize: 25))
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        if (word[i] != letter && i < word.indexOf(letter)) {
          firstPart = firstPart + word[i];
        } else if (word[i] != letter && i > word.indexOf(letter)) {
          remain = remain + word[i];
        }
      }
      richText = RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          text: firstPart,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 25),
          children: <TextSpan>[
            TextSpan(
              text: letter,
              style: TextStyle(color: color, fontSize: 25),
            ),
            TextSpan(
                text: remain,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 25)),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
    return richText;
  }
}
```

the problem is inside the ontap method that when i found the position i can not  convert it to index to get the real char that clicked if it is c chnage the color other wise show toast.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58145606/make-specific-parts-of-a-text-clickable-in-flutter. It shows how to make text clickable in a RichText with a TextSpan.