# Store bold character in string in Flutter

Tags: string, flutter

I am having a string which is hardcoded now (which would be fetched from database in future). I want some parts of the strings to be bold while its stored rather than use rich text (as it would be random with different text). Is there any way to store it as bold using some escape sequences ?

Also is hyper link possible in string in flutter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will this be displayed on a web page?  Then store as html

Comment: Nop. This is for mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. But if you have control over the input's format, what you can do is style it using markdown and use the [flutter_markdown](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown) package to render it.

For hyperlinks, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58145906/3925977) to do it with RichText. Markdown supports hyperlinks though.