# How to detect link automatically in dynamic string at Flutter TextView

Tags: flutter

I trying to made a social post view in Flutter App, user are upload they're content with some contents. I want to detect the hyper links that they mentioned in contents. Is there any solution without using text view package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is already I answered, please explore attached link.
You can use

- splitMapJoin to extract link and
- List of TextSpan Widget to show your dynamic TextView
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/69888589/9719695

Comment: Great!!! It is working. You saved my timer bro, thanks a lot.