# Flutter `TextFormField` with RichText or `SpanText` in `initialValue`

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-textformfield, textspan

I have some `TextFormField`s that I would like to have populated with `RichText` or `SpanText` instead of `String` in initialValue.

Is there a packaged that can help me with this?

The reason is that I am "highligting" phone numbers, emails and links by using this neat trick described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58361777/4475206 and it works like a charm when using it in a 'ordinary' `Text.rich` widget, but not so when using `TextFormField` when we need to set the `initialValue` parameter which just accepts `String`.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59773962/2252830

Answer (score 0):

Checkout one of the following packages:

1. [flutter_quill](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill) (Popular)
2. [rich_input](https://pub.dev/packages/rich_input)

Comment: also check this one, maybe helpful https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill

Comment: It seems rich_input package is not null-sound compatible.