# How to create a URL like link in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am working on a survey project where user can create their question, click a button to generate a link that can be shared to respondent for them to complete the survey.

I need help on how to do this with flutter. Thank you

I had read about deeplink but seems not too clear or meet my need.

Comment: Are you looking for https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/flutter/create?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/53613954/7642429