# How to create hyperlink icon in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, icons

I want to create a hyperlink in Icon:

```
IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit,),
  onPressed: ()=>launch('https://github.com/himanshusharma89'),
)
```

How can we achieve this?

Error:

```
Exception has occurred.
MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method launch on channel plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher))
```

Comment: What is the problem with current code?

Comment: `Exception has occurred.
MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method launch on channel plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher))`

Comment: You can see this it can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55129517

Comment: Please add the exception text to your question

Comment: It seems that you have added dependency in pubspec.yaml and then hot-reloaded the app. The problem is that native dependencies aren't added during hot reload. You should fully stop and start the app again

Comment: Okay, I'll try this and update you soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution, thanks to: [Pavel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6131611/pavel)

```
IconButton(
 icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit,),
 onPressed: () async {
  const url = 'https://github.com/himanshusharma89';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
   await launch(url);
  } else {
   throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
 }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have added dependency in `pubspec.yaml` and then just hot-reloaded the app. Native dependencies aren't added during hot reload. `MissingPluginException` means exactly that native (Android/iOS) plugin implementation is missed.

You should fully stop and start the app again