# Flutter -- how to render a Flutter text with html link

Tags: flutter

I have text that I would like to display using flutter. However, the text contains an HTML link

e.g

```
I have for now, thanks for your time!  Make sure to check <a href='https://yahoo.com/jobs/'><b>yahoo</b></a> .
```

How can I show a link with the text with flutter? Currently, it shows the text as is with the HTML tag.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html) package. Currently supported html tags by this package:

```
a, abbr, acronym, address, article, aside, b, bdi, bdo, big, blockquote, body, br, caption, cite, code, data, dd, del, dfn, div, dl, dt, em, figcaption, figure, footer, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hr, i, img, ins, kbd, li, main, mark, nav, noscript, ol, p, pre, q, rp, rt, ruby, s, samp, section, small, span, strike, strong, sub, sup, table, tbody, td, template, tfoot, th, thead, time, tr, tt, u, ul, var
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the flutter_linkify package

or refer tho one of these answers [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43583411/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-in-flutter-widget#:~:text=7%20Answers&text=Just%20wrap%20an%20InkWell%20around,package%20before%20using%20it%20below.&text=You%20can%20supply%20a%20style,it%20look%20like%20a%20link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43583411/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-in-flutter-widget#:%7E:text=7%20Answers&text=Just%20wrap%20an%20InkWell%20around,package%20before%20using%20it%20below.&text=You%20can%20supply%20a%20style,it%20look%20like%20a%20link).