# AlertDialog content isn't showing any text

Tags: flutter

I have an `AlertDialog` that I want to have hyperlinks within the text. This is what I have currently:

```dart
 await showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: true,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => AgreementDialog());

// AgreementDialog.dart
build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: agreementBloc.agreements,
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<AgreementDocuments> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            SnackBars.errorSnackBar(context, snapshot.error.toString());

            return Spinner();
          }

          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Spinner();
          }

          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Wait'),
            content: Text('test tes test'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                  child: Text('Approve'),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop()),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
```

The above works and will render `'test tes test'`, but now when I try to use the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43592081/4126418) I can't see the `content` text at all. Here is what I've tried:

```dart
return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('One second...'),
            content: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(children: [
                TextSpan(text: 'By clicking Agree, I hereby agree to the '),
                TextSpan(text: 'Blah blah blah'),
              ]),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                  child: Text('Approve'),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop()),
            ],
          );
```

but it ends up blank:

[image]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is gonna be really dumb but I also don't know why my app was doing this...

The color was white so it blended in. I have to set my `TextSpan` to a color other than white.

Comment: Just guessing: Has your Test Device Dark Mode turned on?